# Fancybox gallery images doesn't work if youtube iframe play

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, fancybox

I have embeded youtube videos and some pictures using fancybox (only pictures using fancybox). If I click on the pictures first, those will open correctly with fancybox. Then, if I start a youtube video, which is an iframe, the fancy won't work correctly. It just showing the fancybox's gray background. Why it does that and how to fix it?

```
// This is one of the youtube iframe
<iframe width="290" height="225" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/#YoutubeId#?controls=0&showinfo=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


$("a.fancy").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    'overlayShow'   :   false
});
```

Comment: change `wmode=transparent` to `wmode=opaque` in your youtube trailing parameters. Also add the `wmode=opaque` as an attribute to the `iframe` tag. http://jsfiddle.net/pvXqf/

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It do the same crash bug

Comment: If I remove the iframe I started (display:none; in CSS), I can see the fancybox.

Comment: Do you mean that the jsfiddle doesn't work? it does to me.

Comment: No I don't think so. But I tested on Firefox and IE and all works good. So it's in Chrome the problem.

Comment: Now you really got me confused. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvXqf/) works fine for me in Chrome (v34.0.1847.137 m) and Firefox (v29.0.1) in Windows, What versions are you using? Can you share a link to your page with the issue?